# Add property to (highly used) existing class vs create new class vs conditional?

Tags: c#, angular, class, internationalization, restful-url

I have a site that uses Angular on the frontend and C# on the backend. I have a c# class that obtains data from a database. I have a new field (spanish translation of the value)I want to add, and am not sure which of the following 3 scenarios would be optimal.

This is what the code currently looks like:

```
public class CustomerIssueManager
{
        static public List<GenericRecordDTO> GetCustomerIssues(MyStore db)
        {
            List<GenericRecordDTO> responseDTO = new List<GenericRecordDTO>();

            try
            {
                var customerIssues = db.CustomerIssues.Where(m => m.IsActive && m.Name.ToLower() != "none").OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

                foreach (var c in customerIssues)
                {
                    GenericRecordDTO issue = new GenericRecordDTO();
                    issue.ID = c.ID;
                    issue.Value = c.Name;
                    responseDTO.Add(issue);
                }
            }
       }
}

public class GenericRecordDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value {get; set; } = "";
}
```

These are the scenarios I am considering:

**Scenario 1**:
Is there any significant difference between adding the following to GenericRecordDTO:

```
public string SpanishValue { get; set; } = "";
```

Ramifications: There are many classes that use GenericRecordDTO that won't need SpanishValue

**Scenario 2**:
As opposed to creating another class:

```
public class GenericRecordTransDTO
```

and adding SpanishValue to it?
Solves the problem from scenario 1

**Scenario 3**:
As opposed to keeping GenericRecordDTO.cs as is, but in CustomerIssueManager.cs setting a conditional for spanish site:

```
if(englishSite) { issue.Value = c.Name; }
else { issue.Value = c.SpanishName; }
```

Not sure if I can check for Spanish site at this point or if I need to do it later? And are there any drawbacks to checking spanish site here  vs later in the TypeScript/Angular?

Answer (score 0):

My question would be, why do this on the front end at all? This requires you to handle localization at two levels, while also sending extra data back to the browser that in many cases you do not need.

For me, I would decide the language server side and load content appropriately. If it is a Spanish client requesting the data, then the Name field would be the Spanish name, English user then an English name, etc ... This has the benefit of handling all of the localization on the server side, at least as far as strings are concerned.

However, it is important to understand, localization is more than just text, so you may still need client side formatting for numbers, dates, etc ... For this, I would recommend using a formatting library that takes locale information, then deliver this information from the server via a configuration payload.

As far as detection of the language server side, this could be done quite a few ways. For example:

1. You could send an explicit header or variable with your requests instructing it which language to use.
2. You could use the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser to decide which language you would like to use.
3. You could make it a configuration option that the user can set in their profile, and check a database record for the active user to decide which language you would like to use.

Comment: Hi Shawn . To clarify, I will be adding a new column to the database. I want to be able to get the values from that new column into my application. Thus I'm trying to figure out how to best get it into the C#. I'm not considering that frontend. I'm considering the Angular as the frontend. But the work I'm attempting to do is in C#. The Data Transfer Object already exists, but it exists for the "old" DB Table.